# How is this fraction simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

Based on the snapshot image, I don't understand how they got to the numerator: −1/13h
I actually don't understand how they got to the denominator either?

I appreciate a step by step on how they did it. It's figuratively making pull my hairs out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by $h+13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{h+13}-\frac{1}{13}}{9+h-9}=\frac{\frac{13-(h+13)}{13(h+13)}}{h}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{-h}{13(h+13)}}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\times\frac{-h}{13(h+13)}$$
$$=\frac{-1}{13h+169.}$$

Comment: It took me a minute to wrap my head around that one. That was it. I had done a rough estimate of multiplying both the denominator and numerator by h + 13 but when I did it in my head it didn't seem to play outright. In retrospect, I realized that there were far too many steps for it to play out correctly in my head. Trial and error when not sure - lesson learned. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)